# Derivative of double integral over Region

Tags: integration, derivatives

If one has a function $f_{1}(x)$, which needs to be integrated over a region $x>b$, where $b$ is some one-dimensional boundary, one  writes:
$$
\int_{b}^\infty dx f_{1}(x)
$$
One can, then, take the derivative with respect to $b$, and get:
$$
\frac{d}{db} \left( \int_{b}^\infty dx f_{1}(x) \right) = -f_{1}(b)
$$

How can you generalise this to two dimensions, with a two-dimensional boundary $b(y)$?

First of all, is it correct to write down (?):
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty dy \int_{b(y)}^\infty dx f_{2}(x,y)
$$

Secondly, when taking the derivatives, how does this work exactly (?):
$$
\frac{d}{db} \frac{d}{db(y)} \left( \int_{-\infty}^\infty dy \int_{b(y)}^\infty dx f_{2}(x,y) \right) = ??
$$

Thank you very much,

Laurens

P.S. If this is not clear, please read on to understand why I am doing this.

In Signal Detection Theory, there is a sender and a receiver. The sender typically has the choice between two signals; high and low. The receiver wishes to identify what signal was sent, but communication is noisy. The signal arrives at the receiver with some error, let's assume a normal distribution around the original signal. Due to this error, the high and the low signals overlap somewhat and the receiver is not sure what signal was sent. However, there is some optimal threshold above which it is reasonable to assume the signal was high, and below which is it reasonable to assume the signal was low. Let's simplify by saying this threshold is such that is maximizes the total area of the two normal distributions when one integrates the low distribution to the left of the threshold and the high distribution to the right of the threshold. Now please generalise to two-dimensions, with two signals and a multivariate normal distribution.

Comment: Maybe it helps to know that I wish to set the derivative equal to zero, such that I can optimize for the boundary b, given certain constraints. Maybe in the two-dimensional case, calculus of variation can be used to find the optimal function b(y).

Comment: Derivative in any dimension is defined at a point. In case of your first example it happens that you can define derivative at the boundary because it is a point. As such in higher dimensions you can define something as derivative at a point on the boundary but not derivative on the boundary.